# Google Maps V3 Works as html file but not as a php file in Android browser?

Tags: php, android, html, browser, dictionary

I have a google map v3 webpage (html5) working with an html file extension but fails when php file extension is used for exactly the same code in an Android browser.

Here's the two files with the same code and different file extension:

works with html extension
http://www.wildlifesightings.net/Animals/SubmitAnimalSighting.html?SubCategory=Bird&gCommonName=Mourning Dove&gCommonNameID=66&Mobile=yes

does not work with php extension
http://www.wildlifesightings.net/Animals/SubmitAnimalSighting.php?SubCategory=Bird&gCommonName=Mourning Dove&gCommonNameID=66&Mobile=yes

Does an Android smartphone browser interpret html5 pages differently based on the file extensions .html and .php ?

Comment: blank map is the error, grey color, no map. Seem to have found a solution after a big re-write, if i can figure out which update solved it i'll follow up. i'll leave the same pages up for another day or two in case someone else spots something. thx

Comment: @user2252385 Did you work out what the problem was? Was it really just due to the filename extension?